A line bundle that is relative big over a Zariski dense open subset is also big on every fiber
Let $f:X\to S$ be a proper morphism, let $L$ be a line bundle defined over $X$ which is relative big over $S^0$ where $S^0 \subset S$ is a Zariski dense open subset, prove $L$ is also relative big over $S$.
My attempt. I try to use some upper-semi continuity type theorem (under some nice conditions), on the special fiber $s\in S \setminus S^0$ we have $$h^0(X_s,mL_s)\ge h^0(X_{s'},mL_{s'}),\quad \forall s' \text { in some neighborhood of }s$$
and thus the Kodaira dimension is also $$\kappa(X_s,mL_s)\ge \kappa (X_{s'},mL_{s'}),\quad \forall s' \text { in some neighborhood of }s$$
If the family is flat then we see the only possibility is the line bundle is big on the special fiber also.
However it seems the proposition does not require flatness or any nice assumption? Is my idea correct?

Let $X$ be the blowup of a smooth surface $S$ at a point $P$. Then $L = \mathcal{O}_X$ is relatively big over $S_0 := S \setminus \{P\}$, but not on the fiber over $P$.
